# JMeter json path assert json or array in the response

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, jsonassert

I am doing api testing with Jmeter and using json path assertion to the response body. Problem is response body is giving two response path based on success and failure.

> for failure

```
{
    "response": {
        "error_message": "Invalid input data.",
        "error_code": "Invalid_input",
        "error": true
    }
}
```

> for success

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "attachment_name": "num1.png",
            "attachment_id": 2547,
            "error": false
        },
        {
            "attachment_name": "num2.png",
            "attachment_id": 2548,
            "error": false
        },
        {
            "attachment_name": "num3.png",
            "attachment_id": 2549,
            "error": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Here am adding assertion on "error" path and value but the path changes on the result. 
Added `$.response.error` but this works only for failure case

[image]

Please help me to get correct path and assert in both the conditions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [deep scan operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) `..`, the relevant JSON Assertion configuration would be something like:

[image]

whenever you get `error` JSON attribute with the value of `true` the Assertion will fail the relevant Sampler(s) in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T and Janesh Kodikara... This worked (y)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression for verifying both value (true or false) in the JSON Assertion.

[image]

A sample test plan is available for reference in [GitHub](https://github.com/pragmatictesters/JMeter/tree/master/stackoverflow/answers/59667395)

Hope this is useful.